# Java detect which mouseButton is released on OSX with ctrl click

Tags: java, macos, awt, mouseevent, processing

I try to keep track of if `BUTTON1` `BUTTON2` and `BUTTON3` are being pressed.

The problem is that on OSX `ctrl + click` is seen as a right click.
So if I have the following (using processing):

```
boolean mouse_left_pressed;
boolean mouse_right_pressed;

void setup() {
  size(200, 100);  
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  text("left: "+mouse_left_pressed, 50, 50);
  text("right: "+mouse_right_pressed, 50, 75);
}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  if (e.getButton() == LEFT) mouse_left_pressed = true;
  if (e.getButton() == RIGHT) mouse_right_pressed = true;
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  if (e.getButton() == LEFT) mouse_left_pressed = false;
  if (e.getButton() == RIGHT) mouse_right_pressed = false;
}
```

If I do the following steps:

- click with the left mouse and hold
- press control and hold
- release the left mouse

Then although I have no mouse pressed anymore, the state of `mouse_left_pressed` is still true.
Is there a way to get the actual mouse button that is released?

Answer (score 0):

This is because control+left-click in OSX is equivalent to right-click. Its a bit of a hack, but you could check modifiers as follows:

```java
boolean mouse_left_pressed;
boolean mouse_right_pressed;

void setup() {
  size(200, 100);  
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  text("left: "+mouse_left_pressed, 50, 50);
  text("right: "+mouse_right_pressed, 50, 75);
}


public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  if (e.getButton() == LEFT) mouse_left_pressed = true;
  if (e.getButton() == RIGHT) {
    if (!e.isControlDown()) {
      mouse_right_pressed = true;
    }
    else {
      mouse_left_pressed = true;
    }
  }
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  println(e);
  if (e.getButton() == LEFT) mouse_left_pressed = false;
  if (e.getButton() == RIGHT) {
      if (!e.isControlDown()) {
        mouse_right_pressed = false;
      }
      else {
        mouse_left_pressed = false;
      }
  }
}
```